# Locate data with a set of defined characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in an SQL Server table called [Data]. This column is only supposed to hold **1** or **A** or **a**. An example correct entry could be: **111Aa1aaaaAA1**

A wrong entry could be: **11B1Aa1aaa2aAA1**

The following SQL is meant to locate the incorrect entries but is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable a 
WHERE a.[data] NOT LIKE '%[a]%'
     OR a.[data] NOT LIKE '%[1]%'
     OR a.[data] NOT LIKE '%[A]%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to get the wrong entries:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable a WHERE a.[data] LIKE '%[^a1A]%'
```

... to get all valid entries you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable a WHERE a.[data] NOT LIKE '%[^a1A]%'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=48f19e24008adb2e8b1c9080b41e5358)